# Getting Invalid Key message thrown when creating child records

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am having problems saving `programs` records when using a parent key for the account.

This code fails with error "invalid key" (see bottom for complete):

```
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "programs", actKey)
_, err = datastore.Put(ctx, key, &Program{Name: names[i]})
```

This passes:

```
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "programs", nil)
_, err = datastore.Put(ctx, key, &Program{Name: names[i]})
```

**Complete code:**

```
    // insert test account
    actKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "accounts", nil)
    _, err = datastore.Put(ctx, actKey, &Account{Name: "Chris Olsenio"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Insert test account %v", err.Error())
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    var names = []string {"Low Impact", "Running"}
    for i := 0; i < len(names); i++ {
        key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "programs", actKey)
        _, err = datastore.Put(ctx, key, &Program{Name: names[i]})
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(ctx, "Insert test programs %v", err.Error())
            c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you create an incomplete key:

```
actKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "accounts", nil)
```

Which you use to save an entity:

```
_, err = datastore.Put(ctx, actKey, &Account{Name: "Chris Olsenio"})
```

It works, but note that if the key passed is an incomplete key (it is in your case), `datastore.Put()` returns a new, unique key generated by the datastore. You don't store the returned new key, but you should!

When you try to create and save `"programs"` entities:

```
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "programs", actKey)
```

`datastore.NewIncompleteKey()` expects either a `nil` parent key, of if it is provided, it must be a **complete key** (cannot be incomplete). You pass `actKey` which is an incomplete key, hence the `"invalid key"` error message.

Solution is simple: store the generated new key, and pass the new, complete key as the parent key:

```
actKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "accounts", nil)
actKey, err = datastore.Put(ctx, actKey, &Account{Name: "Chris Olsenio"})
```

If `err` is `nil`, `actKey` will now be a complete key and therefore can be used as parent key when creating other keys with `datastore.NewIncompleteKey()` or `datastore.NewKey()`.

Comment: Missing things like this is what happens when are working until late hours at night. Thanks for the help!