# Google Datastore invalid key error

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to put an item to the Google Datastore using golang.

I'm always running into a `datastore: invalid key` error though and can't figure out what's wrong here. I'm using the `"cloud.google.com/go/datastore"` package.

First I try to get the key for the parent node (not sure this is the right way to do it, but I do end up getting a `datastore.Key` as `parentKey`).

When now creating a new key using the `parentKey` as parent and then trying to `put` the item with this `newKey` I get the `invalid key` error message.

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Supplier")
              .Namespace("inventory")
              .Filter("Name =", "supplier-01")
              .Limit(1)
var s []supplier
parentKey, err := client.GetAll(ctx, q, &s)
if err != nil || len(parentKey) < 1 {
    fmt.Printf("could not find parent key: %v\n", err)
    return
}
newKey := datastore.IncompleteKey("InventoryItem", parentKey[0])
//newKey := datastore.NameKey("InventoryItem", item.Name, parentKey[0])
if _, err := client.Put(ctx, newKey, &item); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("could not save item: %v\n", err)
    return
}
```

I tried it both with the `NameKey` and `IncompleteKey` but no luck with either.

I'm obviously missing something here but can't figure out what it is and how to write my item to the datastore as the child of the other node.

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762520/4466350 ?

Comment: I saw it, but it doesn't apply here, he was trying to write a child to his incomplete key, I can't write the item with the incomplete key itself.

Comment: is parent[0] a complete key itself ?

Comment: You'll need to print out newKey at some point to see what is being passed to Put().

Comment: As far as I can tell it looks good @JimMorrison . `newKey: /Inventory,5634161670881280/Supplier,supplier-01/InventoryItem,0`. I did realize however, that the namespace is not set on the `newKey` only on `parentKey`. Could this be the problem? My understanding was that the parent key would implicitly set the namespace for the new entity but maybe I have to do it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tommy, you nailed it in your comment.  You need to set the namespace on your new key.  I don't see a way in the [Cloud Datastore Go documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Key) to do this implicitly, so you'll have to do newKey.namespace = parentKey.namespace before calling Put().

Comment: Thanks Jim, judging from the docs I would have thought this to be either done implicitly via the parent namespace or have a proper method exposed to set the namespace on the new key like you do for queries etc.